# How to properly connect to FTP via hostname?

Tags: ftp, hostname

I am trying to set up my own sync rule for my Galaxy S7 via an app. I had no luck with setting up SMB share on Windows (where the sync folder is located) so I am trying different approach with FTP server.

I installed Filezilla FTP server and set it up correctly. I can connect to it on my PC (either by typing localhost:port, ip:port or hostname:port). I can connect to it from my phone or any other machine running in the same subnet via ip:port. But how do I properly connect to it via hostname:port? Any device on the same subnet (be it phone, another PC/laptop or the router itself) cannot "see" my machine when I define the target via a hostname. Cannot even ping it.

Main reason why I'm trying to do it this way is because I am connecting to more than one APs with both my laptop and phone (work, home, parents house). I would like to be able to run the sync at any of these places and I thought setting the sync rule with hostname approach would be easier than to have three rules with different IP ranges (as all these places use different range).

Is there something special I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two related ways to approach this...

*Dynamic DNS*

The simpler option is to use a dynamic DNS service to publicly expose the computer with Filezilla FTP server.

Essentially, you would pick a dynamic DNS provider of your choice, install the updater on you "file server", then port forward the appropriate range of FTP ports in your router (likely whatever port Filezilla is listening on, then a range of "transfer" ports matching the ports defined under your server's `Passive mode settings`).

This would solve the hostname and remote connection issues but, as its one major drawback, it requires an internet connection (even if the files were being transferred "locally").  Also note that, in rare instances, the lack of [hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) (NAT loopback) on certain routers can be an issue.

*Local DNS Server*

Alternately, you always have the option of running a local DNS server such as [BIND](https://www.isc.org/downloads/bind/). This would effectively be a replacement for the "Dynamic DNS" portion of the first solution (you would still need to use port forwarding to make the server remotely accessible).

**Pros**

- Allows definition of potentially any hostname you wish to use locally, and allows all devices to connect to that hostname.
- Can be used with custom, internet accessible registered domain names  (e.g. *example.com*).
- Allows "local" transfers, negating the need for an internet connection.
- Potentially solves any issues with hairpinning/NAT loopback.

**Cons**

- More involved setup. Potentially requires periodic (minor) maintenance (such as updating dynamic IPs).
- One computer must remain "on" at all times (serving as a DNS server) or names will not resolve. Furthermore, this computer will be needed to use your local internet connection.
- Introduces some small additional security considerations.